# World of Warcraft Campfire Hack

Tags: world-of-warcraft, cheats

I remember from the early days of WoW (definitely before Burning Crusade) that there was a hack that if you locally replaced the mesh of the campfire you could create arbitrary geometries in your client that would allow you to basically walk over thin air when seen from other clients. Apparently, back in those days Blizzard didn't check file integrity.

I recently tried googleing this, but I couldn't find any references to that.

Did this actually work? Are there any screenshots or even videos of that?

Since this hack obviously doesn't work anymore and probably hasn't worked in more than a decade, I don't think this question is against the rules.